# org-mode agenda: sort items with plain time stamp before scheduled tasks

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have an org-file which might look like the following:

```
* Appointments
** Meet someone important
<2018-02-15 Thu 08:00-09:00>

* Discussions
** TODO Discuss something with someone
    SCHEDULED: <2018-02-15 Thu 08:00-09:00>
```

Generating the agenda results in something like

```
8:00-9:00 Scheduled: TODO Discuss something with someone
8:00-9:00 Meet someone important
```

Is there a simple way to change the sorting of the agenda to sort entries with a plain time stamp before scheduled items, that is I would the agenda prefer to look like

```
8:00-9:00 Meet someone important
8:00-9:00 Scheduled: TODO Discuss something with someone
```

I had a look at the documentation for `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` but this looked quite complicated and I could not figure out how to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little hard to figure out `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` the first time around. If you look at the value (say, with `C-h v`), it's a list of lists. The individual lists describe the sorting to be used in a specific "context", like `agenda` or `todo` for different kinds of agenda views.

The default value is:

```
((agenda habit-down time-up priority-down category-keep)
  (todo priority-down category-keep)
  (tags priority-down category-keep)
  (search category-keep))
```

So for the `agenda` view, it will sort first to put habits at the end (that's what the `-down` means for it), then entries with time of day first, priority in decreasing order, and keep the default order of categories.

So what you want sounds like `ts-up`, to keep active timestamps early first. Therefore, we want the first value to look like:

```
(agenda ts-up habit-down time-up priority-down category-keep)
```

The easiest way is to customize the variable and add the `ts-up` there.